Modify beamer CambridgeUS theme to move logo to footline
I would like to place the (scaled down) logo to the right of "frame # / total frames" in the CambridgeUS beamer theme. How could that be done?

Please always include a short, but compilable test file which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a document environment.

As a quick hack, you could add your logo to the page number in head/foot template:
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\addtobeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}{}{\quad\smash{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-duck}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  abc
\end{frame}

\end{document}



Nice, it worked! I also used \raisebox to align the logo a little lower
